# Binary matrix with row and column sum constraint

Tags: python, matrix

I want to find all the combinations of a binary matrix (ones and zeros) of size **18 x 9** where each **row is equal to 5** and each **column is equal to 10**.

Also each block must have a 1 in each column.

The total number of combinations of that grid size is... well, too much to iterate over:
`2 ** (18 x 9) combinations = 5,846,006,549,323,611,672,814,739,330,865,132,078,623,730,171,904`

Although there are only 9!/(5!4!)=126 combinations of rows to make a row equal 5. With 18 rows, that's still a lot 64,072,225,938,746,379,480,587,511,979,135,205,376

However, each block must have at least a 1 in each column which must limit the number of combinations.

I wonder if I can break it down in to block combinations so it's potentially 6 blocks of 9 columns... which is then only 18,014,398,509,481,984 (obviously didn't factor in the work to work out the blocks first)

I figure the power of `numpy` has the ability but I can't work it out.

I have done a couple of examples in Excel by hand

[image]

Comment: You have 19P10 = 158789030400 possible columns and 9P5 = 15120 rows. This is a pretty big search space to get all the combinations!

Comment: @jeremycg are you saying that is all the combinations to meet the criteria?

Answer (score 0):

Binary matrix with row and column sum constraint.

```
solve(4^3^2^x - 2^162 == 0, x)
```